# Insert from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, insert

I want to insert two columns from table 1 into a new table and a string value into a 3rd column in the new table. I will be doing this across thousands of tables and can't seem to find an answer on how to write the sql statement.

something like:

```
INSERT INTO newtable(a, b, c)
select (a, b)
FROM table 1
AND VALUES("c-string")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into table_2(a,b,c) select a,b,'your_string' from table_3;
```